# How to pass an anonymous function to Jquery's click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code making use of Jquery's `click()` event handler below.

```js
//advance automaton by one step
 $('#nextstep').click(function() {
  if (canAdvanceAutomaton) {
   runAutomaton(logicalGrid);
  }
 });
```

I thought that `.click()` accepts an anonymous function, so I tried changing my code to the one below.

```js
//advance automaton by one step
 $('#nextstep').click = () => {
  if (canAdvanceAutomaton) {
   runAutomaton(logicalGrid);
  }
 };
```

I believed these two pieces of code would be equivalent, but it turns out the latter version doesn't run my `canAdvanceAutomaton` function when I click the html id with `#nextstep`, and I don't see any errors in the console. Can anyone tell me why these two ways of calling `.click()` are not equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both codes are using anonymous functions, but in the second, you're trying to *assign* to the `click` property, when you should be *passing* the arrow function to the `.click` *method*:

```
$('#nextstep').click(() => {
  if (canAdvanceAutomaton) {
    runAutomaton(logicalGrid);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Your first function is anonymous. Your second one is *also* anonymous. The only difference between them is that the first is a traditional function and the second is an arrow function (which doesn't have its own `this` binding). More about the various different forms of functions (named and anonymous) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/22173438#22173438).
2. The problem with your second thing is you're not *calling* `click`, you're *assigning to* `click`.

If you pass an arrow function into `click`, it'll work, but `this` within the function won't be the element that was clicked. (You can still get it from `currentTarget` on the event object it receives, though.)

```
$('#nextstep').click((e) => {
    // You can use `e.currentTarget` to know which was clicked
    if (canAdvanceAutomaton) {
        runAutomaton(logicalGrid);
    }
});
```